# Subset specific rows with vector of identifiers - warning messages

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to subset specific rows with a vector of identifiers.

Here is my data

```
data = rbind(c('B11008Z', 'Men', '13'),  c('B11040Z', 'Women', '14'), c('B11040E', 'Women', '12') ) 
colnames(data) <- c('id', 'sex', 'age') 
data = as.data.frame(data)
```

When I enter the personal id one by one, there is not problem.

```
data[data$id == 'B11008Z', ]
data[data$id == 'B11040Z', ]
```

However, when I create a vector with the identifiers I want, I get warning messages

```
idSelect = c('B11008Z', 'B11040Z')
data[data$id == idSelect, ]
# or 
data[which(data$id == idSelect), ]
```

Could you help me understand why there is an issue here.

Comment: `==` can compare one-to-one element form RHS and LHS. You need to use `%in%` instead. You can illustrate how `==` gives wrong result with a simple example such `1:2 == c(1:2, 2) ; 1:2 %in% c(1:2, 2)`

Comment: You can use `%in%` instead `==`. For example, `data[which(data$id %in% idSelect), ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commands depends on equality and this requires an atomic data, but instead you gave a vector. Instead of this, you can use operators as @davidArenburg has mentioned.
You can do this by first forming a list of T/F and then retrieve the list according to corresponding value of the list.

> data$id %in% idSelect
>       [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

```
data[data$id %in% idSelect, ]
```